# Error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: kotlin

My class:

```
class Manager (var name: String, var nationality: String) {

    constructor(agent: String): this() {}
}
```

returns the following error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

<init>(String) defined in Manager
<init>(String, String) defined in Manager
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Hint: what constructor is `this()` calling?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what `this()` is doing here? I've grabbed the code from a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class has a primary constructor that takes two arguments, and then you define a secondary constructor that takes one argument.

Now, as per the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors):

> If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor
>   needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or
>   indirectly through another secondary constructor(s).

You're trying to do that by calling `this()`, but since you don't have a zero-argument constructor (primary or secondary), this results in a compilation error.

To fix, for example, you can call your primary constructor from your secondary constructor as follows:

```
class Manager (var name: String, var nationality: String) {
    constructor(agent: String): this(agent, "") {}
}
```